# SQL - nested aggregates

Tags: sql, max, having, average

I have this:

```
    SELECT BRAND_ID, CAST (ROUND (AVG(PROD_PRICE), 2) AS NUMERIC (9, 2)) AS 'LARGEST AVERAGE'
    FROM LGPRODUCT
    GROUP BY BRAND_ID
```

and it displays a bunch of average prices, per brand, just like it's supposed to.

But what if I only want to display the highest number? Or the lowest?

I have been trying to use MAX in all kinds of different ways and have tried using WHERE and HAVING.

What am I missing?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have mentions the `RDBMS`, the query below will work on most rdbms.

```
SELECT  BRAND_ID, 
        CAST (ROUND (AVG(PROD_PRICE), 2) AS NUMERIC (9, 2)) AS 'LARGEST AVERAGE'
FROM    LGPRODUCT
GROUP   BY BRAND_ID
HAVING  CAST (ROUND (AVG(PROD_PRICE), 2) AS NUMERIC (9, 2)) =
        (
            SELECT  MAX(xx)
            FROM
            (
                SELECT  CAST (ROUND (AVG(PROD_PRICE), 2) AS NUMERIC (9, 2)) as xx
                FROM    LGPRODUCT
                GROUP   BY BRAND_ID
            ) s
        )
```

one advantage of the query above, is it handles duplicates (*`BRAND_ID`s having the largest average*)

Comment: maybe it could be simplier if you can tell me the database server you are using `:D`